# gem install permissions issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running the following command in macOS Catalina terminal:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install json
```

and getting this error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

Comment: remove old folder and reinstall ruby

Comment: How this relates to objective-c? Recommend to delete or move to ruby tag or something.